# How to set screen height to device height in html?

Tags: html, css

In html pages we use width=device-width with meta tag to say that width should adjust according to the device width. In the same way i want to height also to adjust according to the device height.
I used

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.5">
```

But it didn't change anything.
Is there any other way i can adjust height according to the device height in html or css?

Comment: This https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-height might be helpful for you..

Comment: No, sorry. It didn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using height=100vh. or 100%